# Using Rank-Nullity Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T$:$V\rightarrow W$ and $S$:$W\rightarrow U$ are linear transformations:

How do we define $\text{rank}(ST)$ and $\text{null}(ST)$? I know $\text{rank}(S)=\text{dim}(\text{Im}(S))$ and $\text{null}(S)=\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(S))$.

Is it $\text{rank}(ST)=\text{rank}(S)+\text{rank}(T)$ or $\text{rank}(S)\cdot \text{rank}(T)$ or $\text{rank}(S\circ T)$

Comment: No, the rank of the composition is not the sum or product of the ranks; that's far too large, as seen by taking $S = T = \text{id}$ and $V = W = U$.

Comment: Yes, because $ST$ is shorthand for $S \circ T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{Rank}(S)+\operatorname{Rank}(T)-\operatorname{Dim}(W)\le \operatorname{Rank}(ST)\le \min\{\operatorname{Rank}S,\;\operatorname{Rank}T\}$

Comment: What is $W$? [I have to write something here because the system doesn't let me just write "What is $W$?"]

Comment: The domain of $S$

Comment: Oh, I see. However, the first inequality sign must be $\le$ instead of $<$.

Comment: yes i'll just correct it ,thnxx